# MySQL -Dynamic SQL not able to figure error

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `WhileLoopProc`()

BEGIN

DECLARE x INT;

SET x = 1;

loop1:  WHILE x  <= 213 DO

        SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT Units, NAV FROM jbequity.nav WHERE ClientID =', x ,'ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1');

   PREPARE stmt FROM @s;

     EXECUTE stmt;

   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

 SET  x = x + 1; 

    END WHILE loop1 ;

END
```

Comment: So what's the error? Please edit your question to include the error.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY Date LIMIT 1' at line 1.     Date is one of the column in the table.

Comment: It works fine if i remove 'BY Date LIMIT 1'  , but i need to keep it

Comment: You ought to put the error message **in the question** not in a comment.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `ORDER BY Date` And `LIMIT 1` one at a time to see which piece is causing the error, then google the one that doesn't work to learn how to use it.

**Edit**

I suspect the problem is that you are missing a space in front of `ORDER BY`